# How do I serve a single file in a location directive?

Tags: nginx

How do I return a single file in location directive without any fallbacks? try_files needs at least two. This seems simple but I can't find it in the docs or examples.

```
location / {
      try_files one_file; # => wrong number of parameters
}
```

Answer (score 14):

The simplest way is to use the ability to redirect to an error code if the file doesn't exist.

```
location / {
      try_files /theOnlyFile.html =404;
}
```

Comment: I (was) trying to avoid the 404. try_files does_not_exist.html one_file seems to be the only solution

Comment: how about using the same file as first and second parameter

Comment: @user492922 "I (was) trying to avoid the 404." Why? You want to have a 500 error if the file doesn't exist? (which is what happens).

Comment: I was hoping for more debug info.

Comment: @user492922 "I was hoping for more debug info." Why? Or what type of debug info?

Comment: Not sure, really. I was thinking of it as an exception that was being caught. Anyway I found the error_log level wasn't set high enough to be useful to me. Problem solved.